# Celery is not updating Django database related task

Tags: python, django, django-models, redis, celery

I have a somewhat heavy task that involves bulk creating data into a django models with postgres database. I am using celery to run the task see task function below

```
from os import PathLike

import pandas as pd
from app.models import MyModel
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task()
def db_operation(csv_file: PathLike) -> None:

    dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    dataframe.dropna(subset="code", inplace=True)
    dataframe = dataframe.drop_duplicates(subset=["code"], keep="first")

    dataset = [
        MyModel(code=row.code, title=row.title)
        for row in dataframe.itertuples()
    ]

    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(dataset)

    return "finished"
```

I call the task when the API is called using the celery `delay` like so `db_operation.delay("path_to_file.csv")`

On my flower dashboard I can see that the task is executed when I call it and it shows as successful, however the database does not get updated. If I run the same task without the celery `delay`, it updates the database.
Just to be sure that celery is working I created another task

```
from time import time

@shared_task()
def dummy_task_for_confirmation()
    time.sleep(20)
    print("hello world")
    return 2*20
```

this operation works without any issues.

This is making me think that the issue is somehow coming from the django ORM not being able to execute database operations on celery, but I maybe very wrong. I want to know how to execute the `db_operation` task on celery so that it updates the database successfully.

I am using redis as the broker and the only celery related variables in my settings is

```
# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.getenv("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND")
```

my model looks like so

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

Comment: are you using this in a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure celery to depend on django configuration.

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('settings')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

More details are available here: [Celery Django configuration](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)